# Renaming layer raster by overlay vector using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, splitting, overlay

I split my raster .tiff into several rasters using a vector mask. Now I am wanting to rename those rasters by the id of the polygon used to split.

How do I rename each raster by the id of the overlay polygon using PyQGIS?

[image]

[image]